# Assignment to a 2d list

Tags: python

I was having a go at making a simple machine learning program so I could understand more about AI, but ran into a problem. My program has a 2D list (101 lists of 3 Boolean values (303 total)). It does several loops, and has to set 1, or 2 values from one of the sub lists to True in each loop. When running my program, all values changed to true far too quickly. At first, I thought this might be due to bad luck with `random()`, but then I saw that all the values changed after only 90 to 100 loops, which should be impossible.

I decided to experiment in the shell.

```
>>> Choises=[[False]*3]*101
>>> Choises[1][1]=True
>>> Choises
[[False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False]]
```

Why on earth did it change the 2<sup>nd</sup> value of **each** list, rather than just the 2<sup>nd</sup> value of just the 2<sup>nd</sup> one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens here is that when you create your list, you are multiplying the same reference over and over. So:

```
choices = [[False] * 3] * 101
```

A better way to achieving what you want is:

```
choices = [[False for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(101)]
choices[1][1] = True
```

Comment: Best to stay out of the habit of using `[...] * n` altogether if you don't actually need to; `[[False for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(101)]`.

Comment: @chepner Why is this?